# Form json using php json_encode failed

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

By using below code

```
$data = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM list";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data['title']  = $row['title'];
        $data['name']  = $row['name'];
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

I got 1 result, I can get full result if I do $data[] = $row['title'], but I want to make the result like this

```
{'title' : ['title 1','title 2'], 'name':['John','Amy']}
```

Comment: where does `'name':['John','Amy']` come from ?

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the title in each loop iteration.  You need to accumulate all the titles and then set it in your data array.

```
$data = array();

$sql = "SELECT title FROM mainlist";
$result = $db->query($sql);

$titles = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $titles[]  = $row['title'];
    }
}

$data['title'] = $titles;

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: what if I have other column like name? should I keep creating new array for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$titles = array();
$names = array();

$sql = "SELECT title,name FROM mainlist";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $titles[] = $row['title'];
    $names[] = $row['name'];
  }
}
echo json_encode(array("title" => $titles, "name" => $names));
```

**UPDATE**

Updated my code to let you manage an undefined number of columns as result

```
$out = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_cineteca";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $keys = array_keys($row);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
        $out[$keys[$i]][] = $row[$i];
    }
  }
}
echo json_encode($out);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why? I think it's a good answer to your question. :)

Comment: if I have 6 column I will have to create 6 array variable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest away is probably this:

```
$rows = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM list";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: what is $sth? and $r?

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem. I want to format json so create a neat rest api. how would u handle complex data? assume u have 6 column ?

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve by using group_concat on each of the columns in your query.  That way you do not need to loop the result again and add column etc...

```
$sql = "SELECT group_concat(title) as title,group_concat(name) as name FROM list";
$result = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
```